# Calling Angular2SocialLoginModule function calls not supported

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am new to angular js2. Currently I am working with a web application, which uses angular2 for front-end. In this application I have used angular2-social-login for authentication purpose. But when I run the npm start I got the below error

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'Angular2SocialLoginModule', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/html/ngtest/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/html/ngtest/src/app/app.module.ts

When I google it, some one says that it is beacause of using angular cli in the project. But I uninstalled angular cli, still problem persists.
Did any one know how to solve this issue?

My app.module.ts code is below

```
import { Angular2SocialLoginModule } from "angular2-social-login";
let providers = {    

 "facebook": {
  "clientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "apiVersion": "v2.8"
}, 
 "linkedin": {
  "clientId": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
}, 
"google": {
  "clientId": "xxxxxxxxxx"
}

};
@NgModule({
 imports: [
     Angular2SocialLoginModule.initWithProviders(providers),
 ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have called this module in header.component.ts, please see the header.component.ts file

```
import { AuthService } from "angular2-social-login";
@Component({
selector: 'app-header',
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
providers: [Modal]
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(public _auth: AuthService){ }

 signIn(provider){
 this.sub = this._auth.login(provider).subscribe(
 (data) => {
console.log(data);
   }
 )}
logout(){
this._auth.logout().subscribe(
(data)=>{


//return a boolean value.
}
)}
}
```

The above is my code, Please have a look. If any more details needed please comment

Comment: Please add code

Comment: only need app.module.ts?

Comment: We need also place where you are calling `Angular2SocialLoginModule` function

Comment: k, I will add it

Comment: @yurzui, I have added the code, If any more details needed please comment

Comment: please go through the npm package link : https://github.com/heresy/angular2-social-login-example/issues/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

In angular2-social-login v.3.0.0 you can write:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [ 
     Angular2SocialLoginModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(){}
}

Angular2SocialLoginModule.loadProvidersScripts(providers);
```

### Old version

Remove

```
imports: [
  Angular2SocialLoginModule.initWithProviders(providers),
],
```

And try this:

```
import { Angular2SocialLoginModule, AuthService } from "angular2-social-login";

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    AuthService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    Angular2SocialLoginModule.initWithProviders(providers);
  }
}
```

Comment: can u please go through the  link,https://github.com/heresy/angular2-social-login-example/issues/1

Comment: Did you remove `imports: [
     Angular2SocialLoginModule.initWithProviders(providers),
 ],`? I tried my answer with aot

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
export class AppModule {
    constructor() {
        Angular2SocialLoginModule.initWithProviders(providers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then try to use `AuthService` inside your application

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to fix the above problem:

```
export class AppModule {
 constructor() {
}}
Angular2SocialLoginModule.initWithProviders(providers);
```